# I can't use chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: google-chrome-extension

After the page is loaded, I need to run a javascript code on the page, but every time the console comes up with this error Error handling response: TypeError: chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function

```
{
    "name": "Covid-19 Stats UK",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "latest covid data of UK",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "Sampurna Chapagain",
    "action":{
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Latest Covid Report"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["script.js" ]
        } 
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "notifications",  
        "<all_urls>",
        "background",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "history",
        "background",
        "proxy"
    ]
}
```

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
    let tab = tabs[0];

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { 
      code: `
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-title');
        if (buttons.length >= 2) buttons[1].click();
        
 
      `
    });
  });
```